# If Autosys EEM is down at one side, will WCC of other side work?

Tags: high-availability, autosys

In our firm's Autosys infrastructure, we have a primary environment and a secondary environment and we have a highly available architecture. This means that when one site is down, the other site takes the primary role thanks to the tie breaker. However, I have noticed that when data server is up and EEM is down on one side, we are unable to login to wcc of even the other side. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

So you have both EEM's enabled in autosys_secure? You should have both setup there and also under WCC have each pointing to both EEM's as well.

check the EEM on the WCC server:
Connect to WCC server get where wcc_config is and then:

```
wcc_config -u username --displayeem
```

It should show you all the EEM's that are configured on it.

Comment: Yes. everything is done. Still, when one EEM is down, we are unable to login to wcc of the other site

Comment: As a followup query, how can I confirm if WCC is pointing to both EEM?